# Unity Shader Graph Package Installation Error

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I had reached for here while struggling with some problems about applying a Package to Unity.

### Problem

I’m trying to apply “**Shader Graph [v. 12.1.10]**” package into **Unity [v. 2021.3.20.f1]** but there is a problem like below

[image]

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.shadergraph@12.1.10\Editor\Generation\Targets\BuiltIn\Editor\ShaderGUI\MaterialAssemblyReference\RawRenderQueue.cs(12,24): 
error CS1061: 'Material' does not contain a definition for 'rawRenderQueue' and 
no accessible extension method 'rawRenderQueue' accepting a first argument of type 
'Material' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

[image: RawRendererQueue.cs in 'Shader Graph' package]
[ ^ **RawRendererQue.cs** in '**Shader Graph**' package ]

[image]
[ ^ **Material.cs** that has a method named **rawRendererQueue()** in **UnityEngine** ]

It seems that package can’t access “Material” class in Unity Engine,
judging by neither “**Go to Definition**” nor “**Code Highlighting**” on “**Material**” Class that delivered to ReadMaterialRawRendererQue(**Material** mat) does not working.
But I don't know How can I solve this problem.

### What I’ve tried?

- **reinstall** Shader Graph Package (but same)
- install **another version** Unity **[v. 2021.3.22f1]** and apply Shader Graph Package (but same)

### Ps.
What I really want to do with Shader Graph

As a side note, I am going to make **a shader for 2D plane** that **visualize 1 * 1 cell grid** like below video course,
[ [Showing grid on a map in Unity - Grid Placement System P2 by **Sunny Valley Studio**](https://youtu.be/nKF4Pwb-6Ow) ]
but I got off on the wrong foot with applying a package.

Comment: Have you tried deleting "Library" directory and restarting the project? If create an empty project and import Shader Graph package in it, does the issue repeat?

Comment: @stazik Sorry for late to check comment and I aprreciate for your attention on my Question

I would also try create an empty project [for 21.3.20f1, 21.3.22f1, 22.2.14f1] but it return same sympton.

Deleting the Library folder was a new way of doing it, but it still causes the same symptom.

Comment: @stazik I apreciate you give me attention for this question

Comment: could you further share the project on github or another source? I tried to repeat the issue, but for me, shader graph works correctly. rawRendererQueue is detected

Comment: You might have another rouge `Material` class mucking about in your project. It can either be in your own scripts or some random package.

Comment: Do you have a "Unity UI" folder in the packages folder?

Comment: @stazik Sorry for late Here is link that store the Unity  project[v. 2022.2.14f] which I attached Shader Graph[v 14.0.7]
[ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E5ySHSXf9B07bagf46ryomffX9RdDTXA/view?usp=sharing ]

Comment: @Voidsay I hope so.. But It appears same in the new Project

Comment: @shingo hmm.. In "Packages" folder there just exist manifest.json and packages-lock.json, but, In Library > PackageCache folder, It has com.unity.ugui@1.0.0 folder

Comment: Thank you very much for your deep interest.
First of all, the goal what I want(grid pattern material) solved it by creating one more Tilemap
But, I don't know why I can't apply the package